# Centering tables that are adjacent and left aligned to the size of a dynamic table

Tags: html, css

Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/Xb4gV/

My problem is that I want to have the 2 tables to the left centered as the 3rd table on the right will increase in size(grid view). I would like them centered. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on what your trying to accomplish, but you can give this a try. Going off of what you said you want all tables to be left aligned and centered in the middle of the page but you want the third table to be able to be revisable with no size restrictions, correct? If so this will work:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="center">
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            text
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
<table id="t2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            text
        </td>
    </tr>       
</table>
<table id="t3">
    <tr>
        <td>
            text</br>
            text</br>
            text</br>
            Resizable and centered
        </td>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
clear: left;
float: left;
left: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
 }
.center{
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
right: 50%;
}
#t1{
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
}

#t2{
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
}

#t3{
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
}
```

You can add text to any of the tables cells and it will always re-size and center itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just add width of your parent div as like this

```
#wrapper{
 vertical-align:top;
 margin: 0 auto;
overflow:hidden;
width:200px;
border:solid 10px red;    
}
```

Live demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/Xb4gV/57/